# How do I optimise my home network for wifi calling

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'd like to use Wifi calling when I'm at home, but my phone rarely says that Wifi Calling is available, and I've never made a successful Wifi Call.

Does anyone have any recommendations for settings to tweak on my router that might fix things?

- The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S21 5G - definitely supports Wifi calling.
- It's enabled and working on the phone - it behaves flawlessly when I'm at work* - crystal-clear calls all the time, so my home network + internet connection is the culprit.
- The WAN connection should be good enough - I'm in the UK with FTTC and close the cabinet, so most of the time it syncs at full speed - 80 meg down, 18 up.
- Wifi network has SSIDs for both the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks - the phone connects on 5 GHz.
- Router is an [AVM FRITZ!Box 7530](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7530/). I'm considering upgrading to a Wifi 6 or 6E router, so I'd be open to suggestions if any there are any brands that have good support or optimisations for Wifi calling.
- Phone network is Three (UK).

To be clear - when I say "Wifi Calling" I'm talking about placing a public phone network call (ie. dial a number), not using apps like Skype or WhatsApp (which are no good for calling businesses or government services).

Any ideas on how I can make Wifi calling work better?

*I've spoken to our IT department, who said they hadn't done anything special, so no help there.

Comment: Is UPNP enabled on your home router?

Comment: I recommend talking to your phone company about it. They might have specific advice for ports to check, settings to enable/disable, etc.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the idea - I've turned on UPnP for my phone (on my router it's a device-specific setting) and also ticked the option to make it a "Priority" device, however those two changes haven't improved things.